# Unable to get string array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a array which contains text of selected values of a multi select bootstrap chosen-select.
But i am not getting desired output like:
["Navy", "Dark Blue", "Light Green"]
What I am getting is:
["NavyDark BlueLight Green"].
What is the reason..

This is my code..

```
$('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').each(function() {
      names.push($('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Comment: Please add html-markup too

Comment: add all relevant code in OP like html and js

Comment: can you show your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this

```
//take a empty arr
var names = [""];
$('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').each(function() {
                $('[name="ci_claimed_for"] option:selected').each(function(){
                    names.push($(this).text());
                });
});
```

then just shift your array:

```
names.shift();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to create a new array and then push into it: just use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function:

```
var names = $('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').map(function() {
     return $(this).find("option:selected").text());
}).get();
```

Remember to chain [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) in the end, because it will return a jQuery collection. Use `.get()` to reference the actual array returned.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  var names = $('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').map(function() {
      return $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  }).get();
  
  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ci_claimed_for">
  <option value="John" selected>John</option>
  <option value="Doe">Doe</option>
</select>
<select name="ci_claimed_for">
  <option value="Jane" selected>Jane</option>
  <option value="Doe">Doe</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be iterating it as follows:

**CODE**

```
var arr=[];
var data=$('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').find("option:selected")
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   arr.push(data.eq(i).text())
}
console.log(arr) //desired result
```

Using the `$('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').text()` will return all the text in array of nodes obtained

Answer (score 0):

For your js code .you need a `$(this)` inside the each .You iterate the each element but not pushing with each element to array

```
 $('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').each(function() {
      name.push($(this).val())
    });
```

**OR**

```
$('[name="ci_claimed_for"]').each(function() {
          names.push($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        });
```